# PHP Pagination - detect current page

Tags: php

What is the best way to detect/print the current page number (pagination)?

I tried two different ways, and now i want to know if there exists a better way to do it.

**I:**

```
$number = 12; //current page number
$all = 40; // all pages
$range = 4; // number of pages shown (up and down)
$min = $number-$range;
$max= $number+$range+1;

for($i=$min; $i<$number;$i++) {
    echo "<a href='#'>$i</a><br/>";
}

echo "$number<br/>";

for($i=($number+1); $i<$max;$i++) {
    echo "<a href='#'>$i</a></br>";
}
```

**II:**

```
$number = 12; //current page number
$all = 40; // all pages
$range = 4; // number of pages shown (up and down)
$min = $number-$range;
$max= $number+$range+1;

for($i=$min; $i<$max;$i++) {
    if($i!=$number) {
        echo "<a href='#'>$i</a><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "$i<br/>"; 
    }
}
```

I also checked the speed of both solutions (using different high-number `$all` values) and first one is faster in most cases.

Thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: which pagination class you are using?

Comment: No class, i wrote it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional alternative (for 0 to 10 pages; replace it with `$min` `$number-1` .. )

```
echo implode("<br/>",
       array_map(function($x){
           return "<a href='..'>$x</a>";
       }, range(0,10))
);
```

Please time it, and let me know. :)